# JWNL Wordnet - accesing derivationally related forms for verbs

Tags: nlp, wordnet

I use Java and JWNL library to access WordNet.
Having Synset object of some verb how can I access his "derivationally related forms".

I tried these things:

```
Synset synset;
...
Pointer[] pointers = synset.getPointers(PointerType.DERIVED);
```

or

```
PointerTarget[] targets = synset.getTargets(PointerType.DERIVED);
```

but there is no result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's turned out that I have to use:

```
Pointer[] pointers = synset.getPointers(PointerType.NOMINALIZATION);
```

Answer (score 0):

Haven't worked with JWNL. But I to faced such problems.

You should remember ***not all words are verbs and not every verb has "derivationally related forms".*** 
Basically try more words.

Try "**dash**" has derivations - bolt and sprint